# Create all possible cards with itertools and zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I am trying to create all possible combinations of poker cards. So, I ran:

```
import itertools as it
ranks = (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Jack','Queen','King','Ace')
suits = ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds')
for i in zip(ranks, it.repeat(suits, 14)):
    print(i)
```

And got:

```
(2, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
(3, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
(4, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
(5, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
(6, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
(7, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
(8, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
(9, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
(10, ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
('Jack', ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
('Queen', ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
('King', ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
('Ace', ('Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'))
```

What would be an efficient way to get `['2 of Spades', '2 of Clubs', '2 of Hearts', ...]` from this list of tuples?

My current method is:

```
cards = []
for card in zip(ranks, it.repeat(suits, 14)):
    rank, suits = card
    for suit in suits:
        cards.append("{} of {}".format(rank, suit))
```

Is there a better way to do this? What is it?

Comment: `it.product(suits, ranks)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you!

Comment: @rassar but that isn't any more efficient than your way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need itertools for that. List comprehension will work fine:

```
cards = [ "{} of {}".format(r, s) for r in ranks for s in suits ]
```

Comment: True. But is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @rassar By 'more efficient' you mean more compact code? Because I don't think there is a more efficient solution.